# How to import the DeepBeliefSDK in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-learning

I successfully ran a Linux example in a java application , but when I tried to import the Android example into Android Studio, I got runtime error. The error was that android studio can't find the `jnidispath` library even if I manually paste it to `deepBelief.jar` or add as dependencies.

In a next step I tried to build it from source, because I got info that the `jpcnn` library is corrupted(https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK/issues/48 ), but it did not help anyway...

My question: How do you import the DeepBeliefSDK in Android studio?

LogCat from my app with linked deepBelief.jar library in jni folder

```
08-23 23:35:44.496 7913-7913/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.google.sample.helloandroidjni, PID: 7913
                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-arm/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)
                                                 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:776)
                                                 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
                                                 at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
                                                 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
                                                 at com.jetpac.deepbelief.DeepBelief$JPCNNLibrary.<clinit>(DeepBelief.java:11)
                                                 at com.example.glm.jni.Main.onCreate(Main.java:21)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Adding my last stacktrace where I`m using System.loadLibrary("libjnidispatch");

```
08-23 23:41:46.476 8837-8837/com.google.sample.helloandroidjni E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.google.sample.helloandroidjni, PID: 8837
                                                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.sample.helloandroidjni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "liblibjnidispatch.so"
                                                                                 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                                 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                                                 at com.example.glm.jni.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:13)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: Adding the JAR is correct (see example link). JNI is a hardware interface, though. If the library isn't compiled for certain Android instruction sets, then you can't use it on those Android devices. For reference, the Github example only has ARM  listed in the libraries folder https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK/tree/gh-pages/examples/AndroidExample

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know about CPU limitation, but I think the problem is somewhere else (library written in Java 6 maybe...). I read here https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK/issues/69 , that this guy ran it, the problem is that in IntelliJ IDEA, but that is not far away from the Android-studio...

Comment: I linked to the Android example. Have you cloned the project and try to run that?

Comment: Yea many times, even in Android-studio 1.5 and ended with runtime error, when I ran example app..

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the stacktrace? The error on the github issue is for a camera error, which not all devices use similar camera apis